# How to download an HTML page with all dependencies?

Tags: php, javascript, web, download, copy

I'm working on this project where I basically need to be able to put an html button on any page (which can be login protected) and once the user hits that button, the page html and dependencies (css,js,images etc) should be sent to a remote server.

Initially I got it work by using an iframe and hidden form and posting the url of the page to a remote server when the user clicks the button. Then I used wget within exec to get the page and dependencies. However, this will obviously not work for a protected page.

So my next approach is to send the innerHTML of the page via the form to a php script on remote server. Then I tried using simplehtmldom to run through ,  and  tags , converted the relative urls to absolute urls , stored them in arrays, and replaced the url to a path within the same directory. Then I applied wget on all the arrays and downloaded these dependencies.

However, I'm stuck again as there are background images in CSS and embedded html code in javascript.

Can someone please suggest a better solution ?

Thanks

Comment: what is stopping you from CSS and JS parsing?

Comment: I'm just starting to think that this is not a good approach. I mean I would also have to resolve the urls in CSS and js files and they may not resolve correctly.

Comment: If the site is AJAX based, your technique will fail.

Comment: Not sure what you mean there ? I just want to capture stuff after the dom loads.

Comment: I'm not sure if its relevant, but were you aware the browsers can save a tarball like version of a webpage that includes all the dependencies inlined into the multipart html source? I know it doesn't really answer your question, but thought I'd mention it. save as .mht file

Comment: Well the thing is I'm not really looking to do this via browsers. I want to do by embedding code on my pages and capturing the screen.

Comment: Do you have shell access on the remote server?  If so, I'd suggest having the client send a message to the server to execute `wget -p -k [thepage]`. Make the server pull the content rather than have the client push it.

Comment: @apsillers yes I control the remote server and thats precisely what I did earlier with wget. But wget cannot pull pages that are protected by a login script.I want to be able to put this button  on a login protected page and still capture the page. The css, images, js are usually in the public domain so if I can get the links, I could download the dependencies.. that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: Aha, I see.  The issue also exists with intranet Web resources (the client can see it, the server cannot).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is ever going to work.
The fact is that unless your site is very simple indeed (i.e. has very few dynamic parts) and exists on the click->load->static paradigm which really isnt the way any modern site works anymore, you're always going to have some missing pieces/dependencies.

If it's a super simple site you can perhaps just send the html and then add in a `<base>` href to the head of the duplicate?

As you know, these days sites are more like applications and your really need the whole site inclusive of all 'moving parts'

other things which might be worth looking at:

1. Using ftp functions of PHP/.NET/Java/Ruby etc to fire
   template/css/img directories to a new location.
2. perhaps looking at the HTML 2 PDF/Canvas tools which are out there and can show a
   visual representation of the current state of the site to another
   location.

Comment: Well anyway I can parse the inline JS and CSS for background image url

Comment: try the < base > tag it will mean you can use all the assets from one place on the html in another